# How to create a Product Space like the one from Atlas of Economic Complexity?

Tags: d3.js

I need to learn how to build and use a Product Space for a research. I was trying to learn how to make exactly one from the Atlas of Economic Complexity [Link](https://atlas.cid.harvard.edu/explore?country=231&queryLevel=location&product=undefined&year=2020&productClass=HS&target=Product&partner=undefined&startYear=undefined). I would really appreciate someone that could guide me on what tools do I need to learn for this. Thanks a lot!.

I managed to download the data from the following link . But I couldn't make anything. I dont really know how to use D3.js